# Flutter: Share composite JPG with PNG overlay

Tags: flutter, image, dart, overlay, android-sharing

We want to have an award pinned on photos. This simple stack should do it.

Zoom and Pan functionality was asked for, which is why I have an `InteractiveViewer` with the `IgnorePointer` for the overlay.

```
class _OverlayImagesScreenState extends State<OverlayImagesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: Text('Image Overlay')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              InteractiveViewer(
                  boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  minScale: 0.1, maxScale: 10.0,
                  // The actual image will come from an upload in the future
                  child: Image.asset('assets/figures/Teacher02.jpg')), 
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10, left: 40,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  child: IgnorePointer(
                    ignoring: true,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/demo_png/teacher_of_the_year.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // HOW DO I SHARE / SAVE THE IMAGE IN A ZOOMED AND PANNED STATE 
              // WITH THE OVERLAY ON TOP?
            },
            child: Text('Share'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

However, now the users want to export this, and share it with their friends via SMS or Social media.

How do I share / save the composite image in a zoomed-in and panned state with the overlay on top?